# Macro/Function to find a string in a column and find it in a sentence in sheet 2 and return respective value in column 3

Tags: vba, excel

Related to Excel

Input

I have date in column B and cheque number in column D in sheet 1.
I have a sentence in column D in sheet 2, this sentence will have values any of the values of Column D of sheet 1.

Requirement :
The first cheque number (column d sheet 1) has to be searched in column D in sheet 2, if in any of the sentences the value is found then Column B (Date from Sheet 1) has to be pasted in Column H in sheet 2. Also mark in Sheet 1 Column H "Y" if found and "N" if not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we will dim the variable

```
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, a As Range
Dim Rws2 As Long, rng2 As Range, c As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
```

We need to set the worksheets before we set the ranges

```
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
```

Set the range for sheet1, this will determine the last row in columnD and set the range

```
With sh
    Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(Rws, "D"))
End With
```

This will set the range for sheet2

```
With ws
    Rws2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(Rws2, "D"))
End With
```

Now we will start a loop to find the check #'s

```
For Each a In Rng.Cells
```

Will want to find the 1st check number

```
  Set c = rng2.Find(what:=a, lookat:=xlPart)
```

If it is found then we want to place the date in column H

```
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Cells(c.Row, "H") = a.Offset(0, -2)
```

And put a "Y" in column H sheet1

```
 sh.Cells(a.Row, "H") = "Y"
```

If not found, then we want to place a "N" in column H sheet1

```
 Else: sh.Cells(a.Row, "H") = "N"
end if
```

Then Loop to the next "a" in column D sheet1

```
    Next a
```

All together it will look like this.

```
Sub Loop2()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, a As Range
    Dim Rws2 As Long, rng2 As Range, c As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With sh
        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(Rws, "D"))
    End With

    With ws
        Rws2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(2, "D"), .Cells(Rws2, "D"))
    End With

    For Each a In Rng.Cells
        Set c = rng2.Find(what:=a, lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Cells(c.Row, "H") = a.Offset(0, -2)
            sh.Cells(a.Row, "H") = "Y"
        Else: sh.Cells(a.Row, "H") = "N"
        End If

    Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.. Its working, small issues are there, I am trying to find out, If am not able to do then will check with you again :) your rocking :)